# Selecting unique values of different columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table (orders for ex) which has Multiple Columns.

```
products    categories  subcategories
--------------------------------------

prod1       cat1        sub1
prod1       cat2        sub2
prod2       cat3        sub6
prod1       cat1        sub1
prod5       cat2        sub8
prod2       cat1        sub1
prod1       cat7        sub3
prod8       cat2        sub2
prod2       cat3        sub1
```

Now I can write three different queries to get distinct values

```
var prod = (from p in _context.orders select p.products).ToList().Distinct();
```

similarly I can write it for others.

Now I need to get the distinct values of each column in a single query for which the result needs to look like

```
products    categories  subcategories
--------------------------------------

prod1       cat1        sub1
prod2       cat2        sub2
prod5       cat3        sub6
prod8       cat7        sub8
                        sub3
```

My ClassType for unique fields looks like this

```
public class UniqueProductFields
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure how to do this in an efficient manner so that I dont have to write three methods. The table is in the database (hence the need for optimization)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it an absolutely unchangeable requirement to use Linq? Why do you need it to be returned in a single query?

Suggestion: Use SQL. It *can* be done in a single query but you won't like the query. I'm assuming SQL Server (can be done differently for other DBMSes).

```sql
WITH V AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT
      V.*
   FROM
      Orders O
      CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES (1, O.Products), (2, O.Categories), (3, O.Subcategories)
      ) V (Which, Value)
),
Nums AS (
   SELECT
      Num = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY V.Which ORDER BY V.Value),
      V.Which,
      V.Value
   FROM
      V
)
SELECT
   Products = P.[1],
   Categories = P.[2],
   Subcategories = P.[3]
FROM
   Nums N
   PIVOT (Max(N.Value) FOR N.Which IN ([1], [2], [3])) P
;
```

## [See this working at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dbe4ba21e1978cebbd0ad626dd306c3d)

Output:

```
Products  Categories  Subcategories
--------  ----------  -------------
prod1     cat1        sub1
prod2     cat2        sub2
prod5     cat3        sub3
prod8     cat7        sub6
null      null        sub8
```

If you are bound and determined to use Linq, well, I can't help you with the query-style syntax. I only know the C# code style syntax, but here's a stab at that. Unfortunately, I don't think this will do you any good, because I had to use some pretty funky stuff to make it work. It uses essentially the same technique as the SQL query above, only, there's no equivalent of `PIVOT` in Linq and there's no real natural row object other than a custom class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var data = new List<Order> {
            new Order("prod1", "cat1", "sub1"),
            new Order("prod1", "cat2", "sub2"),
            new Order("prod2", "cat3", "sub6"),
            new Order("prod1", "cat1", "sub1"),
            new Order("prod5", "cat2", "sub8"),
            new Order("prod2", "cat1", "sub1"),
            new Order("prod1", "cat7", "sub3"),
            new Order("prod8", "cat2", "sub2"),
            new Order("prod2", "cat3", "sub1")
        };
        int max = 0;
        var items = data
            .SelectMany(o => new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> {
                new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, o.Products),
                new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, o.Categories),
                new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, o.Subcategories)
            })
            .Distinct()
            .GroupBy(d => d.Key)
            .Select(g => {
                var l = g.Select(d => d.Value).ToList();
                max = Math.Max(max, l.Count);
                return l;
            })
            .ToList();
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, max)
            .Select(i => new {
                p = items[0].ItemAtOrDefault(i, null),
                c = items[1].ItemAtOrDefault(i, null),
                s = items[2].ItemAtOrDefault(i, null)
            })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(row => Console.WriteLine($"p: {row.p}, c: {row.c}, s: {row.s}"));
    }
}

public static class ListExtensions {
    public static T ItemAtOrDefault<T>(this List<T> list, int index, T defaultValue)
        => index >= list.Count ? defaultValue : list[index];
}

public class Order {
    public Order(string products, string categories, string subcategories) {
        Products = products;
        Categories = categories;
        Subcategories = subcategories;
    }
    public string Products { get; set; }
    public string Categories { get; set; }
    public string Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

I suppose that we could swap this

```
.Select(i => new {
   p = items[0].ItemAtOrDefault(i, null),
   c = items[1].ItemAtOrDefault(i, null),
   s = items[2].ItemAtOrDefault(i, null)
})
```

for this:

```
.Select(i => new Order(
   items[0].ItemAtOrDefault(i, null),
   items[1].ItemAtOrDefault(i, null),
   items[2].ItemAtOrDefault(i, null)
))
```

Then use that class's properties in the output section.

Comment: Great skills Erik!, Made me so curious i had to try it!. By the way, there's a minor error with an alias in the PIVOT operator, your using V.Value instead of N.Value :) Can't edit since it is only one character :P

Comment: @AarónBC. Sorry about the two typos. I wrote it entirely from memory and without checking syntax. It's been a full year since I last touched SQL Server. I added a db<>fiddle where you can try it.

Comment: You could also do with just [one CTE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da6e3d46faa8c80b84d9363fa803e626). Not sure if that would make much improvement in terms of performance, though.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any advantage of `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`, rather than simply an  anonymous type `IEnumerable<int, string>`?

Comment: @onedaywhen There’s no such thing as `IEnumerable<int, string>`. You can theoretically use `IEnumerable<dynamic>` with an anonymous type, and I tried that at first, but it was blowing up, and I wasn’t using Visual Studio which would make diagnosis easy so I just switched to KVP. That’s perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you won't be able to do it in a single query. Before thinking how would you do it with C# think how would you do it in SQL; I might be wrong but to me you'll be writing 3 querys anyway.

If you notice some performance issues and this is your actual code:

```
var prod = (from p in _context.orders select p.products).ToList().Distinct();
```

You may want to start by removing the `.ToList()` extension method beacuse that is retrieveng all records to memory and only after that the distinction is applied.

That's because your query expression (`from p in ...`) returns an `IQueryable` and calling `.ToList()` on it <s>makes it `IEnumerable`.</s> force the current formed SQL query to run and bring the results to memory.

<s>The difference in this case is: **Deferred execution**</s>

See: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable/

Comment: Yeah I understand the IEnumerable Vs IQueryable. I only want to reduce the number of methods that I need to write. I tried using SQL, but couldnt get further as the examples were using CTEs at times.

Comment: Well, if you find a method to do exactly that please post it here =). If you think about SQL, a single query returns rows, not separate collections of data. One distinction rule might be OK with one column but have conflicts with another.

Comment: It's a little misleading to say that that calling `ToList()` makes the return type `IEnumerable` and also that the main difference is deferred execution, because that is almost implying that `IEnumerable` is eager execution which it is not. `ToList()` technically makes the return type `List<T>`, which happens to implement `IEnumerable`, but so does `IQueryable`, so they're *both* `IEnumerable`, and all `IEnumerables` are technically deferred execution, though the implementing class could do the majority of its work up front.

Comment: The trick is that certain Linq *methods* force immediate execution, and others do not. `Select` and `Where` are deferred-execution, but `GroupBy` and `Order` are eager execution. This makes sense if you think about it, because the latter two can't emit even a single value until the entire set is enumerated—any value it emitted early might not end up being complete (GroupBy missing an item from a group) or might be the wrong first item (OrderBy out of order).

Comment: Erik, you're right about my misinterpretation of the IEnumerable interface, i'll correct that. About the trick, it its not exactly in the Linq methods, it depends on the provider and how the implementation was made. Take for example LinqToSql, if you use OrderBy in a IQueryable the return type is an IOrderedQueryable which doesnt execute immediately.

Comment: The lambda code we use in the filters of Where, in OrderBy and others is used to form the SQL Query (talking about LinqToSql). A hint we could use is the method parameteres, if it asks for an Expression, it might use deferred execution, but it is not granted, again, it depends on the implementation of the provider.